# How to read a file from specified string?

Tags: windows, powershell

For exemple, I have the following file:

```
...
Thu Sep 24 15:08:21 2019
SMON: enabling cache recovery
Archived Log entry 22 added for thread 1 sequence 27 ID 0xedf06523 dest 1:
Thu Sep 25 13:08:45 2019
CJQ0 started with pid=33, OS id=316
Thu Sep 26 15:13:45 2019
Starting background process SMCO
Thu Sep 26 15:13:45 2019
SMCO started with pid=19, OS id=2340
...
```

I need to read from my current day Thu Sep 26 13:08:45 2019.

I made this, but it bring only the lines with the date.

```
Get-Content $alertlog | Select-String $(Get-Date -Format "ddd MMM dd")
```

The result:

```
Thu Sep 26 15:13:45 2019
Thu Sep 26 15:13:45 2019
```

What I need:

```
Thu Sep 26 15:13:45 2019
Starting background process SMCO
Thu Sep 26 15:13:45 2019
SMCO started with pid=19, OS id=2340
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the -Context Parameter

```
Get-Content $alertlog|select-string $(Get-Date -format "ddd MMM dd")  -Context 0,1
```

Comment: Great, verry simple!

Comment: Isn't necessary in my case, but if I wanted to read from a specified string until other string? it's possible?

Comment: @DaniloNeto It's possible, but not via `-Context`.